# Radio button in tkinter changes value of other set of radio buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

When I click on a radio button in the first frame, it changes the corresponding radio button in the second frame. For example, if I click on `o1` in the first frame, the value in the second frame will also change to `o1`. I tried setting `tristatevalue=None` like what I've seen online but it is not working.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

class q:
    def __init__(self, question, options, answer):
        self.question=question
        assert type(options)==list
        self.options=options
        self.answer=answer


root=Tk()
score_div=Frame
q_div=Frame(root)
q_div.grid(row=1)
q_list=[q("Q1", ["o1", "o2", "o3"], 1),
        q("Q2" ,["o1", "o2", "o3", "o4"], 0)]

for num, i in enumerate(q_list):
    print(q_list)
    exec(f"Q{num}=IntVar(value=None)")
    exec(f"Q{num}div=Frame(q_div)")
    Label(exec(f"Q{num}div"), text=i.question, font=("Calibri", 18, "bold")).grid(sticky=W)
    for num1, j in enumerate(i.options):
        Radiobutton(exec(f"Q{num}div"), text=j, variable=exec(f"Q{num}div"), value=num1, tristatevalue=None).grid(sticky=W, padx=20)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: using `exec` is not the best approach here. It makes the card very hard to read and debug. Instead of this, you should store the variables and widgets in a dictionary.

Comment: Why a dictionary though? What would be the key value pair?

Comment: The key would be the thing you're trying to create as a variable name. Or better yet, just the number. The value would be the widget or variable. . For example, `vars[num] = IntVar(value=None); frames[num] = Frame(q_div)`, etc.

Comment: To clarify one would be able to use f-strings in dictionaries keys right

Comment: Yes, fstrings can be used to create dictionary keys.